# How to fade in a React component using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fadein

I want my React component to fade in when it is mounted. The outermost DIV of my component has the inline style `display:none`. In my `componentDidMount()` method I have the following:

```
let el = document.querySelector('.myElement');
el.style.transition="opacity 2s";
el.style.opacity=1;
```

However, the components remain hidden. If I add `el.style.display='block';` to the above method, the component appears immediately without any fade in effect.

I have tried the same using the jQuery `fadeIn` method and that works just fine:

```
$(el).fadeIn(2000);
```

So, is it possible to do this using pure JavaScript?

Note: The component in question is used in two scenarios. The first is when a new component is added to the page. The second is when the component renders to the page on page load and contains data from the database. I only want the fade in transition to occur when a new component is added to the page.

Comment: you could do something like that but you would be including jquery for no good reason i would advise you to look at https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion or https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup avoid the jquery pest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy.

In your react component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let el = document.querySelector('.myElement');
  el.classList.add('fade-in');
}
```

In your stylesheet:

```
.myElement {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s opacity;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

When your component mounts, it's going to have an `opacity: 0` immediately and then a `fade-in` class that's going to set it to `opacity: 1` with a transition of 2 seconds.

Comment: If you have a transition that lasts say 10 seconds and you want to fire an event after the end of the transition, how would you do that?

Comment: Also, this component needs to be visible when it is mounted with data previously saved in the database, but only needs the fade-in effect when a new component is added to the page.

Comment: @JoeTidee just use `setTimeout` to accomplish the 10 seconds delay and fire the event, if you use [gsap](https://greensock.com/gsap) you could do it without a `setTimeout`, it's a very powerful animation tool, I highly recommend it, check it out.

Comment: @JoeTidee for the component, just hide with an `opacity: 0` the child component you want to fade-in, and make the parent component behave as normal, visible, that's the power of component-based apps.